# How can I animate the text of both my divs at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want two separate divs with different text to have the same typing animation simultaneously. I am using [iTyped.js][1], for the animation. I have tried Object.create, jQuery.extend, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) to create two different objects. Solved it. Used a different jQuery plugin. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3shx2bj/20/

```js
$('#element').typeIt({
     strings: ['This is my string!']
}); 

$('#el').typeIt({
     strings: ['Enter your string here!', 'Another string!'],
     autoStart: false,
     breakLines: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/4.3.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div><span id='element'></span></div>

<div><span id='el'></span></div>

</body>
```

Comment: @Satyantan your fiddle is not working, kindly update your fiddle

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwalla now?

Comment: cool now ur fiddle is working I haven't used that js but let me check if I come up with a solution, I will post it.

Comment: You could initiate second one after the first one is finished, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/nqhnd0nf/

Comment: @azs06 Thanks but I need them together.

Comment: Seems like your library isn't working with multiple divs .. (https://jsfiddle.net/h3shx2bj/19/) one is overwriting the other one and kind of taking together the result. Is that "type" library on github? You got the real name cause there are some many `*type*` libraries. maybe there is already a bug or pull request with a solution to your problem